# Spring MockMvc redirectedUrl with pattern

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking

I have a simple `PersonController` class that provides `save()` method to persist the object from http post request.

```
package org.rw.controller;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

import org.rw.entity.Person;
import org.rw.service.PersonService;
import org.rw.spring.propertyeditor.TimestampPropertyEditor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/person")
public class PersonController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    TimestampPropertyEditor timestampPropertyEditor;


    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Timestamp.class, "dob", timestampPropertyEditor);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(Model model, Person person) {
        Long personId = personService.save(person);
        return "redirect:view/" + personId;
    }

}
```

As the `save()` method returns as `return "redirect:view/" + personId;`. It will be diffrerent for every request. it may be like `"view/5"` or `"view/6"` depending on the id of the object that has been persisted.

Then i have a simple class to test the above controller with spring mocking.

```
package org.rw.controller;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.rw.service.UserService;
import org.rw.test.SpringControllerTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class PersonControllerTest extends SpringControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @Test
    public void add() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/person/add", new Object[0])).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


    @Test
    public void save() throws Exception {
        UserDetails userDetails = userService.findByUsername("anil");
        Authentication authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);

        mockMvc.perform(
            post("/person/save", new Object[0])
                .param("firstName", "JunitFN")
                .param("lastName", "JunitLN")
                .param("gender", "M")
                .param("dob", "11/02/1989")
        ).andExpect(
                redirectedUrl("view")
        );
    }


}
```

now here i have a problem that `redirectedUrl("view")` is rejecting value `"view/5"`. I have tried `redirectedUrl("view*")` and `redirectedUrl("view/*")` but its not working.

---

***Edit :***

Here I have got a workaround as per below

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(
    post("/person/save", new Object[0])
        .param("firstName", "JunitFN")
        .param("lastName", "JunitLN")
        .param("gender", "MALE")
        .param("dob", "11/02/1989")
).andExpect(
        //redirectedUrl("view")
        status().isMovedTemporarily()
).andReturn();

MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

String location = response.getHeader("Location");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\Aview/[0-9]+\\z");
assertTrue(pattern.matcher(location).find());
```

but still i am looking for the proper way.

---

***update:***

I have posted the same issue on [spring jira here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10789) :

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since spring 4.0 you can use [redirectedUrlPattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#redirectedUrlPattern-java.lang.String-) as pointed by [Paulius Matulionis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1147529/paulius-matulionis)

As of spring 3.x this is not supported out of the box but you can easily add you custom result matcher

```
private static ResultMatcher redirectedUrlPattern(final String expectedUrlPattern) {
    return new ResultMatcher() {
        public void match(MvcResult result) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\A" + expectedUrlPattern + "\\z");
            assertTrue(pattern.matcher(result.getResponse().getRedirectedUrl()).find());
        }
    };
}
```

And use it like build-in matcher

```
 mockMvc.perform(
    post("/person/save", new Object[0])
        .param("firstName", "JunitFN")
        .param("lastName", "JunitLN")
        .param("gender", "M")
        .param("dob", "11/02/1989")
 ).andExpect(
        redirectedUrlPattern("view/[0-9]+")
 );
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `4.0` it is available in Spring itself.

Please check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#redirectedUrlPattern-java.lang.String-).

Comment: and here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#redirectedUrl-java.lang.String-