# Spring MockMVC redirectUrlPattern throws "No Ant-style path pattern"

Tags: java, pattern-matching, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2952196/1429387) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17834034/1429387). I want to match URL pattern so I write my test according to answers in these questions.

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

// Ant pattern, example URL: /courses/1/edit
private static final String CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/[0-9]+/edit";
// ...
    this.mockMvc.perform(
            post("/courses/create")
                    .with(csrf())
                    .param("name", "New Course"))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrlPattern(CREATE_SUCCESS_URL));
```

I'm not sure about the right Ant pattern syntax, so I've also tried variations like:

- `CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/{[0-9]+}/edit"`
- `CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/\\d+/edit"`
- `CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/\\d/edit"`
- `CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/{\\d+}/edit"`
- `CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/{id:\\d+}/edit"`
- `CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/{id:[0-9]+}/edit"`

But I always get an exception

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No Ant-style path pattern
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:36)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:66)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.lambda$redirectedUrlPattern$3(MockMvcResultMatchers.java:153)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
    at by.naxa.stackoverflow.CoursesTest.givenNameWhenSubmitCreateCourseThenSuccess(
    ...
```

One more thing. Pattern `CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/?/edit"` works ok, but I'd like to make sure I match digits only.

Spring Boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid Ant path pattern for your requirements would look like:

```
CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/{[0-9]*}/edit"
```

or

```
CREATE_SUCCESS_URL = "/courses/{\\d*}/edit"
```

---

This `AssertionError` is caused by the following method inside `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher`:

```
public boolean isPattern(String path) {
    return (path.indexOf('*') != -1 || path.indexOf('?') != -1);
}
```

So any string containing `*` or `?` will work.